# Create an Asset List Using Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a code using Macro, but with no luck.

The task can be simply defined as, when the user enters a Serial Number such "AB123" **anywhere in column I**, a list should appear automatically in columns in (J, K, L). please the the attached picture

If there is any other way to do that without using Macro, I am glad to hear it.

Thank you in advance, I hop that I make myself clear.

The pic. shows whenever the **RED** Serial Number is entered. The Highlighted columns in green should appear.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"a list should appear automatically down in columns in (I, J, K, L)."*? Probably a screenshot might help to explain this.

Comment: You should use a `ListObject/Table` . [Excel Tables Tutorial #1 How to Create and Use Excel Tables 2013 2010 2007 365](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03ysshhXZk8)

Comment: I just edited my question and provided a picture, kindly consider it.

Comment: Should the green columns be dependent on the number in red?

Comment: Yes they depends on the red number.

Comment: Then I think more detail needs to be provided on that relationship.

Comment: Take this as an example, what are the parts of an "iPhone X" basically, it consists of Battery, Screen, Front cover, Back cover, .. etc. So, the task simply whenever the user write "iPhone X" the parts should appear automatically.

Comment: It is exactly the same relation, but more complicated so I want a hint to start.

Comment: @HassanRumaeh A hint: Have a look at the `=VLOOKUP` formula or the VBA equivalent [WorksheetFunction.VLookup Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-vlookup-method-excel) to lookup data in a matrix. This should be possible without the use of VBA • Your question lacks to much information to give a detailed answer, so I can't give you more than that hint.

Comment: As @Aneta said, please show us the code you've written, it will give us an indication of your intentions and what issue your having.  We're not sure how you want to trigger your code, button or event.  We don't know where your parts information is located (Database? Another Worksheet? Flat File?) and how is the data organized?  Is there other data in the worksheet?  Will lines need to be inserted or are we only ever dealing with the last SN entry?

Comment: @JosephC Thank you for your assistance, I got that task and I am not an expert in Excel. However, the information will be located in another sheet, and the only thing that the user will enter is the SN, and regarding the other questions I do not have the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Something for you to think about. Put this code in your Sheet. Double-click the sheet name and a windoe to enter code will appear.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Me.Range("J:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Target.Value = "AB1234" Then
            Me.Range("J:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
            Me.Range("J:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
         End If
    Else
        'Nothing
    End If
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

Me.Range("J:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End Sub
```